# How to get Method annotated with given annotation in springboot / java app

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-aop

Is there a way to directly get hold of a method(non-static)  annotated with given annotation present in a given object? I don't want to iterate over list of all methods and check if the given annotation present or not.
In below sample code, I have used dummy method(not exist) **getMethodAnnotatedWith()** . I need to replace this with actual method.

```java
public class MyController {
  @PostMapping("/sum/{platform}")
  @ValidateAction
  public Result sum(@RequestBody InputRequest input, @PathVariable("platform") String platform) {
    log.info("input: {}, platform: {}", input, platform);
    return new Result(input.getA() + input.getB());
  }
}
```

```java
class InputRequest {
  @NotNull
  private Integer a;
  @NotNull
  private Integer b;

  @MyValidator
  public boolean customMyValidator() {
    log.info("From customMyValidator-----------");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class AspectClass {
  @Before(" @annotation(com.example.ValidateAction)")
  public void validateAspect(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    log.info(" MethodName : " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
    Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
    log.info("args[0]==>"+args[0] +", args[1]==>"+args[1]);

    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();
    Parameter[] parameters = method.getParameters();
    Method customMyValidator = parameters[0].getType().getMethodAnnotatedWith(MyValidator.class);  // InputRequest class type which has a method annotated with @MyValidator

    customMyValidator.invoke(args[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of making things complicated just for the sake of being able to freely naming your method and then annotating it by a known annotation, why don't you just make each class with a validator method implement a specific interface with a given validator method name, implement that method and just intercept method with arguments implementing that interface, then call the method right on the object? If the method is in a known position of the argument list such as first, second, third from left or right, you can even directly bind the argument via `args()`.

Comment: Then you do not need any reflection for method calls, no special libraries or Spring `AnnotationUtils` etc. Just let me know if you are interested in this approach (please understand if first, though). Then I can write a corresponding answer. Like R.G, I could suggest a way to do directly what you asked for, but I believe this is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309898). You are asking with a specific technical solution in mind instead of focusing on what you want to achieve.

Comment: If u have psuedo code handy with you then I want to look into it. I don't know how exactly that work. My purpose is to perform bean validation using inbuilt hibernate annotations and also apply my custom logic which is based on path-variable. Issue which I m trying to solve here is to first perform normal validation and then run my custom validation rule (path variable based) and then merge both set and throw error if present.

Comment: I don't do pseudo code, I would rather prepare something that compiles and runs, but I would use AspectJ without Spring so as not to have to prepare a full Spring example. But the aspect syntax would be the same in Spring AOP, don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my stand-alone AspectJ [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I just imported some Spring classes. The syntax would be the same in Spring AOP.

**Helper classes:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Result {
  public Result(int i) {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(METHOD)
public @interface ValidateAction {}
```

**Custom validator interface (*not* annotation):**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public interface MyValidator {
  boolean validate();
}
```

**Class implementing custom validator interface:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class InputRequest implements MyValidator {
  private Integer a;
  private Integer b;

  public InputRequest(Integer a, Integer b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean validate() {
    System.out.println("Performing custom validation");
    return false;
  }

  public Integer getA() {
    return a;
  }

  public Integer getB() {
    return b;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "InputRequest(a=" + a + ", b=" + b + ")";
  }
}
```

See? Instead of annotating the validator method, you just override the interface method. It is just as simple as before, but more type-safe and feels more "standard-ish". It will also be much easier to handle by AOP, as you are going to find out below.

**Controller:**

The controller looks just the same as before. You still have the method annotated with `@ValidateAction` and taking `InputRequest` as its first parameter.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;

public class MyController {
  @PostMapping("/sum/{platform}")
  @ValidateAction
  public Result sum(@RequestBody InputRequest input, @PathVariable("platform") String platform) {
    System.out.println("input: " + input + ", platform: " + platform);
    return new Result(input.getA() + input.getB());
  }
}
```

**Sample driver application:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyController().sum(new InputRequest(11, 22), "foo");
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

The aspect is super simple now, like I said in my comment to your question. The pointcut checks for methods which

- are annotated with `@ValidateAction` and
- have a first parameter implementing `MyValidator`.

Then it binds the `MyValidator` parameter to an advice method argument by `args()`.

Please note that you can omit the trailing `&& execution(* *(..))` in Spring AOP because it only supports method `execution()` joinpoints, while in AspectJ there are also `call()` joinpoints which here would lead to double validation and log output.

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import de.scrum_master.app.MyValidator;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyValidatorAspect {
  @Before("@annotation(de.scrum_master.app.ValidateAction) && execution(* *(..)) && args(validator, ..)")
  public void validateAspect(JoinPoint joinPoint, MyValidator validator) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(joinPoint);
    validator.validate();
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
execution(Result de.scrum_master.app.MyController.sum(InputRequest, String))
Performing custom validation
input: InputRequest(a=11, b=22), platform: foo
```

---

**Update answering follow-up questions:** Please read some documentation. The Spring manual is a good source.

> 1. what does it mean `&& args(validator, ..)`?

It is called argument binding. This specific pointcut designator means: Match all target methods where the first argument matches the type of `validator` in the advice method arguments list and bind the value to that argument. As you see, the argument is declared as `MyValidator validator`. The `, ..` means that any subsequent target method arguments (if any) do not matter. For more information see [this manual paragraph](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing).

> 2. What would happen if more than one class implementing `MyValidator` interface . I mean how would FW figure out that which implementation has to passed while invoking current controller operation ?

FW meaning what? Maybe framework? Anyway, I do not see the problem. Why would the framework have to figure out which implementation there is? That is the beauty of OOP and virtual methods: You do not need to figure out anything because each implementation has a `boolean validate()` which then gets called. It is simple, type-safe, hassle-free. Your solution is neither of these. This approach just works. Instead of asking, why don't you just try?

Comment: Hi @kriegaex thanks for your solution. II have two questions though: 1) what does it mean `&& args(validator, ..)`?   2) What would happen if more than one class implementing MyValidator interface .  I mean how would FW figure out that which implementation has to passed while invoking current controller operation ?

Comment: I updated my answer, also answering your follow-up questions. I would have needed multiple comments to do so.

Answer (score 1):

[MethodUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html) (Apache Commons Lang) can be used to achieve the requirement.

API used in the example code : [MethodUtils.getMethodsListWithAnnotation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html#getMethodsListWithAnnotation-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-)

Aspect Code

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class CallAnnotatedMethodAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(rg.so.q64604586.service.*) && @annotation(rg.so.q64604586.annotation.ValidateAction)")
    public void validateActionMethod() {
    };

    @Before("validateActionMethod() && args(request,..)")
    public void adviceMethod(InputRequest request)
            throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        List<Method> methodList = MethodUtils.getMethodsListWithAnnotation(request.getClass(), MyValidator.class);
        for (Method m : methodList) {
            m.invoke(request, new Object[] {});
        }
    }
}
```

Note : The Retention Policy of `MyValidator` annotation is RUNTIME for this code to work.

If the `InputRequest` instance obtained in the aspect is a proxy , the code will need to be modified to get the actual class of the same.